# Multi call for NSURLConnection with multi UITableView in Same Controller

Tags: iphone, uitableview, nsurlconnection

I have to call two different API in a same view controller and have to show the data on two tableView in same controller, i’m using NSURLConnection for this. but i’m unable to show the result on both of the tableView.

Only urlConnection (for the firstTimeCall) is gave the result . For the secondTimeCall the result is 0.

Can anyone please provide me the samples or able to suggest me the way to do this.

Thanks In Advance.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.



    [self firstTimeCall];
    [self SecondTimeCall];

}

- (void)firstTimeCall
{
    NSURLRequest *request=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://xyza.com/key=init"]];
    responseData=[[NSMutableData alloc]init];
    urlConnection=[[NSURLConnection alloc]initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
    NSLog(@"nsurl FirstTimeCall %@",urlConnection);
}

- (void)SecondTimeCall
{
    NSURLRequest *requestTwo=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://abcz.com/key=init"]];
    responseDataTwo=[[NSMutableData alloc]init];
    urlConnectionTwo=[[NSURLConnection alloc]initWithRequest:requestTwo delegate:self];
    NSLog(@"nsurl SecondTimeCall %@",urlConnectionTwo);
}


- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error{

    if (connection == urlConnection) {
        NSLog(@"Error");
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"Error");
    }

}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response{

    if (connection == urlConnection) {
        [responseData setLength:0];
    }
    else {
        [responseDataTwo setLength:0];
    }

}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data{

    if (connection == urlConnection) {
        [responseData appendData:data];
        NSLog(@"%@",responseData);
    }
    else {
        [responseDataTwo appendData:data];
        NSLog(@"%@",responseDataTwo);
    }


}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {

    if (connection == urlConnection) {
        NSError *error=nil;
        NSDictionary *dic=[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error];
        self.totalData=[dic objectForKey:@"data"];
        NSLog(@"%@",totalData);
        NSLog(@"First Time...............%d",totalData.count);


          [tableViewOne reloadData];
    }
    else {
        NSError *error=nil;
        NSDictionary *dic=[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error];
        self.totalDataTwo=[dic objectForKey:@"data"];
        NSLog(@"%@",totalDataTwo);
        NSLog(@"Second Time...............%d",totalDataTwo.count);


          [tableViewTwo reloadData];
    }


}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if(tableView==tableViewOne){
        NSLog(@"In TableViewOne numOfRow");
        return [totalData count];


    }else{
        NSLog(@"In TableViewTwo numOfRow");
        return [totalDataTwo count];
    }

}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"NewCell";

    if(tableView==tableViewOne){
        NSLog(@"In TableViewOne Cell4Row");
        NewCell *cell = (NewCell *)[tableViewOne dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
        if (cell == nil)
        {

            NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"NewCell" owner:self options:nil];
            cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];



        }

        cell.nameLabel.text = @“Testing1;
        return cell;

    }else{
        NSLog(@"TableViewTwo Cell4Row");
        NewCell *cell = (NewCell *)[tableViewTwo dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
        if (cell == nil)
        {

            NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"NewCell" owner:self options:nil];
            cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];



        }

        cell.nameLabel.text = @“Testing2”;
        return cell;


    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that the two `NSLog` in `didReceiveData` are fine, but it's just that the log in `connectionDidFinishLoading` for the second connection is wrong? This would be because the second half of your `connectionDidFinishLoading`, you're looking at `responseData`, and I assume you meant to look at `responseDataTwo`. I'd also suggest you update your `NSLog` statements to clearly state which is #1 and which is #2 (e.g. in `didReceiveData`, you're just logging, but you don't know which is which (though by looking at the data, I suspect you can make an intelligent guess.).

Comment: BTW, this sort of mistake is easy to happen when you have so much redundant code, where it's easy for a single variable to slip past you, like what happened here. If you used a block-based solution, such as [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking), `NSURLConnection` method `sendAsynchronousRequest`, or your own dedicated network request object, you could reduce the amount of code you have to write here and minimized the chances of this sort of error.

Answer (score 0):

Call methods  [self firstTimeCall];, and  [self SecondTimeCall]; in Synchronous ways. by default this time in ur code you are calling methods in async way.

First call [self firstTimeCall]; method and when you received the response and when you have get call in connectionDidFinishLoading delegate method for firstTimeCall, then start calling SecondTimeCall from here.
Overall first call firstTimeCall adn received its data response from server after completing this call, now call SecondTimeCall.